# ruby: workarounds for nested string interpolation

Tags: ruby, nested, string-interpolation, rubocop, ruby-2.7

In the string
`"#{x ? (x.to_s + ' is ') : ''}ok"`, Rubocop's Style/StringConcatenation suggests avoiding the `+`.
But that requires a nested string interpolation
`"#{x ? '#{x.to_s}  is '  : ''}ok)"`,
which at least in Ruby 2.7 is not expanded:  `#{x.to_s}` is treated like any other literal.

Is the `+` version alright because it's on the fringes of what a style guide could cover, or must one introduce a temporary variable?

```
tmp = x ? '#{x.to_s}  is '  : ''
"#{tmp}ok"
```

---

Context: the string is sent to a logfile.  `ok` is actually a long list of details.  `x` is worth logging, but only when it exists.

Comment: I'd rather use `x ? "#{x} is ok" : 'ok'` in that case.

Comment: Nice flip-flop!  But, unlike this MWE, my actual `'ok'` is a long string that has even more interpolations.  Duplicating that string isn't DRY.

Comment: Can you give a more complete example? Maybe there's a cleaner (more OOP) approach. Besides, I'm curious what you're trying to do ;-)

Comment: Could Robocop simply want you to to write `s1 << s2` or `s1.concat(s2)` rather than `s1 + s2`? Either way, that line of code looks like its been whupped with an ugly stick.

Comment: Balancing efficiency and readability I would be inclined to write `(x ? "#{x} is " : "") << "ok"`. If `"ok"` is a placeholder for a long string, perhaps `str = "ok"; (x ? "#{x} is " : "") << str`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a variable will make this more readable (imo):

```rb
prefix = "#{x} is " if x
"#{prefix}ok"
```

(this relies on the fact that `nil#to_s == ''`)

Comment: If I had to read the code, this is what I would like encountering rather than the ternary inside the interpolated and appended string.

Answer (score 1):

Given that "ok" is actually:([according to the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65850119/ruby-workarounds-for-nested-string-interpolation/65851733#comment116428378_65850119))

> *"...a long string that has even more interpolations. Duplicating that string isn't DRY"*.

I would go with

```
ok = generate_some_long_string()
ok.prepend("#{x} is ") if x
ok
```

This does mutate `ok` but based on my understanding of the question this may actually be desirable.

**Nesting Interpolation**

As an aside and I would not recommend it (because it is difficult to read) but nesting interpolation is completely valid ruby e.g.

```
x="val"
"#{x ? "#{x} is " : ""}ok"
#=> "val is ok"
```

This works because what is inside the interpolation closure is treated like any other ruby code. The inner double quotes open and close a new String rather than closing the first and opening another because the interpolation closure is waiting for a closing curly brace. You could technically do this at any depth.

```
"#{x ? "#{"the #{y = x}ue of"} #{x} is " : ""}#{y.inspect}"
#=> "the value of val is \"val\""
```